# Sidekiq drain also performs new jobs enqueued via perform_in

Tags: ruby, sidekiq, worker

I want to test a worker, that enqueues itself (based on some retry logic).

```rb
class SomeWorker
  def perform
    SomeWorker.perform_in(10.minutes)
  end
end
```

```rb
SomeWorker.perform_async
SomeWorker.drain # => This continously enqueus and runs the job
...assert something...
```

1. It doesnt wait 10 minutes before running it
2. I was thinking that the call to `drain` should run only the first job and, that I would need to call drain again to run more.

What I want my test to look like is

```rb
SomeWorker.perform_async
SomeWorker.drain
...assert something is retrying...
SomeWorker.drain
...assert something is not retrying...
```

How can I test this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SomeWorker.drain` will keep running jobs on the queue until it's empty. If your job queues another one, it will run that as well.

If you only want to run a single job, use `SomeWorker.perform_one`.

[Docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mperham/sidekiq/Sidekiq%2FWorker%2FClassMethods:perform_one)